# How add a Static Class into a Declaration File in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings

I'm creating a **UMD** library in **TypeScript**.
I have my first class, a static one, with a method. My Library is named **SuperLib** and this is the code:

```
export class Security {
  static userExists ( user: string ): boolean {
     ...
  }
}
```

With **Webpack** I generate the JS Lib: `SuperLib.js` and it's working correctly in this way:

```
<head>
  <script src="libs/SuperLib.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var exits = SuperLib.Security.userExists ("user01");
    console.log ("User01 exits? " + exits)
  </script>
```

Now I created the **Declaration File**: `SuperLib.d.ts`. 
I created in this way:

```
declare namespace SuperLib {
  export class Security {
    userExists ( user: string ): boolean;
  }
}
```

**My situation:**

Using my library in a HTML, with that **Declaration File** in **WebStorm**, the Security class is not treating as a static class.

The autocomplete fills as:

`var exits = SuperLib.Security().userExists ("user01");`  << Look the () after security.

I need that shows in this way:

`var exits = SuperLib.Security.userExists ("user01");`

Why? How I can fix it?

Comment: The method `userExists` isn't declared in your declaration file and you're using `new` to instantiate `SuperLib.Security` in your `<script>`, which is not how static classes are supposed to work ([new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)).
Just because it sounds to me like you're writing the `.d.ts` manually: you can let the [TypeScript compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) generate declaration files for you using `--declaration` or `-d`.

Comment: Excuse me @FabianLauer.. I just corrected the declaration file... And I'll try that TypeScript generates it.. I didn't know that it do it!

Comment: No problem. The `static` keyword is missing in the declaration file. If you add that before `userExists`, you should be able to write `SuperLib.Security.userExists('...')`  ;-)

Comment: exactly - after marking method in d.ts `static`, completion works as expected. But even without `static` I don't get `()` after `Security` when choosing it from completion...

Answer (score 0):

In the Declaration file is missing 'static'. The corrected code is:

```
declare namespace SuperLib {
  export class Security {
    static userExists ( user: string ): boolean;
  }
}
```